# How an int can be equal to another function returning long int?

Tags: c, function, types

I've got the following code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

long checks();

void main() {
    int results = checks();
    printf("%d", results);
}

long checks(){
    return LLONG_MAX;
    }
```

**It gives the output of -1**

Despite declaring function prototype how is this file **even compiling?**
int `results = checks();` is supposed to give an error!

Moreover there return type don't match!

**In C return type of a function mustn't be equal to the same data type?**

Comment: after it passes the max value for int it just goes back to the min value for int again

Comment: `LLONG_MAX` is the maximum of the `long long` datatype, which is not necessarily the same as the `long` datatype (in particular, on i86, `int` and `long` are both 4 bytes long, while `long long` is 8 bytes). Compile with warnings on (`-Wall`) to catch these sort of things.

Comment: MSVC gives warning C4305: 'return' : truncation from '__int64' to 'long'. That's because in my compiler, `int` is the same as `long`, but `LLONG_MAX` is the value truncated - not the function return value.

Comment: @WeatherVane: To be accurate, because `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` "*is truncated to `0xFFFFFFFF`*"

Comment: @alk I was unhappy with it becasue OP values are signed, so I deleted it before you commented. I was almost there but was truncating the wrong end.

Comment: What platform is this on? It might even be that `int` and `long` are the same type. They would be on Win32, for example.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: On x86, the size of `long` is not necessarily 32 bits. POSIX uses 64 bits `long` on x86 (I32LP64). 32 bit `long` seems to be a Windows special (AFAIK OS-X also uses 64 bit `long`)

Comment: If `long` and `int` sizes are equal (32 bit), then the issue is here: `return LLONG_MAX;` . A `long long` is returned as `long`.

Comment: Your compiler wants to shout at you. Enable warnings.

Comment: I'm using -Wall and -Wextra flags,but still no warnings..... @Olaf

Comment: @Olaf thanks a lot :D it fixed the warning problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is very "forgiving" with things like that.  Implicit type conversions are usually not errors in C.  Of course, this is a philosophical issue, the modern answer to which is diametrically opposite to what it used to be when the first C compilers were being written.  Nowadays we do not call this forgiving, we actually call it extremely *unforgiving*, because it lets errors go undetected.

You can have most modern C compilers issue warnings for things like that, but you need to examine the documentation of your compiler to figure out how to enable warnings.  (It might be something like "-Wall".)

Comment: I came from C# where these kind of errors were serious! :p

so, in C return type of a function mustn't be equal to the same data type?

Comment: It has nothing to do with functions.  In C you can even do `long a; int b; b = a;`

Comment: That's right the types don't always need to be the same, but you should at least see a warning. C programmers will often look at the warnings and try to eliminate them before running the program.

Comment: @joeytwiddle: Not really reasonable for C. Did you know that `signed char x, y, z; z = x + y;` results in converting `x` and `y` to `int`, producing an `int` sum, then converts the result to `signed char`? Naturally the compiler will do something efficient, but semantically, that's what the notation literally means.

Comment: GCC with CodeBlock in Ubuntu.... fixed it after adding `-Wconversion` as @Olaf suggested :D

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a quick fix,

Most of the things already said by **Mike**....

It should give a warning regarding this implicit conversion...

I had to enable `-Wconversion` flag for the warnings to show up :)